# Index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, matrix

I am trying to make a program that counts the number of steps it takes to reach from starting of the matrix to the center of the matrix, and in the process, I encountered this error, code:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.zeros([5,5])
matrix[0][0] = 1
count = 0
while matrix[2][2] != 1:
    count += 1
    matrix[0][0] = matrix[count][count]
print(count)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Python uses zero-based indexes. So a data structure of length 5 has indexes that go from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix[0][0] = matrix[count][count]
```

You got it the wrong way around. matrix[0][0] is already 1, but then set to 0.

You want:

```
matrix[count][count] = matrix[0][0]
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you are assigning to matrix[0][0] that's why loop is never ending and go out of array index

```
 import numpy as np
    matrix = np.zeros([5,5])
    matrix[0][0] = 1
    count = 0
    while matrix[2][2] != 1:
        count += 1
        matrix[count][count] = matrix[0][0] 
    print(count)
```